# rotate the elements of the given array k times to the right

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, exception

I have made this code to rotate an array by k times. In this when I'm adding **i=0** , it is showing an "ArrayOutOfBounds" exception, and when I'm changing the value of i by 1, it is showing wrong output. Why is it showing this exception? And is there any way I could correct this code?
[image: Output when i=1 and k=3]

```
    public void rotate(int[] nums, int k)
    { int j=0, temp=0;
        for(j=0;j<k;j++)
        {
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
        {
              temp=nums[i-1];
              nums[i-1]=nums[i];
              nums[i]=temp;
            
        }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For `i=0`, `nums[i-1]` becomes `nums[-1]`.

Comment: If **i** is 0, you're trying to get an index of -1 which will raise an `ArrayOutOfBounds` exception. If **i** starts from 1, then you're not dealing with the first number.

Comment: @DavidLee, Is there anything I can change to avoid this mistake and get the correct output in this program?

Comment: Why do you need to iterate k times for each swap? you can do a k-shift directly and the algorithm becomes O(n) instead of O(n*k).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit (from comments above)*: If **i** is 0, you're trying to get an index of -1 which will raise an ArrayOutOfBounds exception. If **i** starts from 1, then you're not dealing with the first number.

Here's the function you can use to rotate integers to the right:

```
public void rotate(int[] nums, int k) {
    int arrLen = nums.length;

    // If the number of times you want to rotate is bigger than the size of the array, get the minimum number of rotations to get the same result.
    while (k > n) {
        k = k - arrLen;
    }
    k = arrLen - k;
    k = k % arrLen;
    int i, m, n, temp;
    int g_c_d = gcd(k, arrLen);
    // Move the value in the i-th index
    for (i = 0; i < g_c_d; i++) {
        temp = arr[i];
        m = i;
        while (true) {
            n = m + k;
            if (n >= arrLen) {
                n = n - arrLen;
            }
            if (n == i) {
                break;
            }
            arr[m] = arr[n];
            m = n;
        }
        arr[m] = temp;
    }
}

// Find the greatest common divisor of two numbers, a and b
public void gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}
```

Let me briefly explain what it does. This is one of the most known algorithms: juggling. You divide the array into the *n* number of sets where *n* denotes the greatest common divisor of the length of the array and the number of times you want to rotate. Then, you move the numbers within sets.

This might be the most efficient in terms of time (as its time complexity is *O(n)*).

Comment: Yes, the other one was showing time limit exceeded, this one works better.

Answer (score 2):

At `i=0` you are trying to access `nums[i-1]` = `num[-1]` which is an invalid position and hence an `ArrayOutOfBound` exception is thrown.
So, the modified version would be:

```java
        for (j=0; j<k; j++)
        {
            for (int i=1;i<nums.length;i++)
            {
                temp=nums[i-1];
                nums[i-1]=nums[i];
                nums[i]=temp;
            } 
        }
```

But the above will rotate the array by `k` times towards the `left` not right as you are shifting the elements towards the left. So, to get the `right` rotation you need to shift the elements from the end of the array. Like:

```
        for (j=0; j<k; j++)
        {
            for (int i=nums.length-1; 0<i; i--)
            {
                // shifting towards the right
                temp=nums[i-1];
                nums[i-1]=nums[i];
                nums[i]=temp;
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be taking a copy of the given array with the values '0' then looping through the given array to obtain a new_index.

**Formula for the New_index for the Clock-wise rotating array:**

```
for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
 int new_index = (old_index+k)%(a.length)
 copy[new_index] = a[old_index]
}

Now the entire function code would be:

    
public static void rotate(int[] a, int k)
    {
     int n = a.length;
     int[] copy = new int[n];
    //  fill the values with zeroes
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
         copy[i]=0;
     }
    //  rotate the array
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int new_index = (i+k)%n;
        copy[new_index] = a[i];
    }
    // Now that the array is copied, copy the elements to the original array. Because they asked to rotate the given array.
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
         a[i]=copy[i];
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
function solution(arr, k) {
  if(k == 0) return arr; 
  if(arr.length == k) return arr;
  if(arr !== undefined && arr !== null){
    let counter = k > arr.length ? k % arr.length : k;
    let rotArray = [];
    rotArray = arr.slice(arr.length - counter, arr.length).concat(arr.slice(0,arr.length - counter))
    return rotArray;
   }
  return arr;
}
```